# CSS to align label and input

Tags: jquery, html, css, input, label

HTML Code Snippet:

```
<fieldset id="o-bs-sum-buginfo">
  <label for="o-bs-sum-bug-ErrorPrefix">Error Prefix</label>
  <input type="text" id="o-bs-sum-bug-ErrorPrefix" name="ErrorPrefix" value="" />

  <label for="o-bs-sum-bug-ErrorNumber">Error Number</label>
  <input type="text" id="o-bs-sum-bug-ErrorNumber" name="ErrorNumber" value="" />
  ....
</fieldset>
```

Using only CSS (or jquery), irrespective of the browser size, I want to pair label and input elements next to each other. I also do have freedom to change tweak the HTML. if required.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

This is one of those things which can be surprisingly tricky to get right.

Many people will suggest using `float:left;` for this. Personally, I really dislike floats; they seem to cause more problems than they solve.

My preference is to use inline-block. This is a display method that combines inline properties (so you can easily align elements next to each other, etc) with block properties (such as being able to specify dimensions).

So the answer is simply to make them both `display:inline-block;` and give the prompts a fixed width, which will make the input fields next to them line up.

You'll also need some sort of line feed or break after the input field, otherwise the next prompt will appear on the same line, which isn't the desired effect. The best way to achieve this is to put each prompt and its field into a container `<div>`.

So your HTML will look like this:

```
<fieldset id="o-bs-sum-buginfo" class="myfields">
  <div>
    <label for="o-bs-sum-bug-ErrorPrefix">Error Prefix</label>
    <input type="text" id="o-bs-sum-bug-ErrorPrefix" name="ErrorPrefix" value="" />
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="o-bs-sum-bug-ErrorNumber">Error Number</label>
    <input type="text" id="o-bs-sum-bug-ErrorNumber" name="ErrorNumber" value="" />
  </div>
  ....
</fieldset>
```

and your CSS will look like this:

```
.myfields label, .myfields input {
  display:inline-block;
}

.myfields label {
  width:200px; /* or whatever size you want them */
}
```

**Edit**:
you can use this plugin for setting the width of each label:

```
jQuery.fn.autoWidth = function(options) 
{ 
  var settings = { 
        limitWidth   : false 
  } 
   
  if(options) { 
        jQuery.extend(settings, options); 
    }; 
     
    var maxWidth = 0; 
   
  this.each(function(){ 
        if ($(this).width() > maxWidth){ 
          if(settings.limitWidth && maxWidth >= settings.limitWidth) { 
            maxWidth = settings.limitWidth; 
          } else { 
            maxWidth = $(this).width(); 
          } 
        } 
  });   
   
  this.width(maxWidth); 
}
```

[from this page in a comment](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2008/07/09/Justify-elements-using-jQuery-and-CSS.aspx)

and you use it this way:

```
$("div.myfields div label").autoWidth();
```

and thats all... all your labels are going to take the width of the longest label

Comment: Works perfect. I would have faced issues without the div container wrapping around label and input.

Answer (score 10):

`#o-bs-sum-buginfo label, #o-bs-sum-buginfo input{display:inline-block;width:50%;}`

Comment: +1 Good Answer, only this Code Snippet -> display:inline-block;width:50%; is enough!

Answer (score 1):

Put the every label with its corresponding input into a p tag. Then add the following css:

```
label{
  float:left;
  width:100px; //whatever width that suits your needs
}

p{
    margin:10px 0; //manipulate the vertical spaces for each input..  
}



<fieldset id="o-bs-sum-buginfo">
  <p>
    <label for="o-bs-sum-bug-ErrorPrefix">Error Prefix</label>
    <input type="text" id="o-bs-sum-bug-ErrorPrefix" name="ErrorPrefix" value="" />
  </p>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: `p` is non-semantic here. It is not a series of paragraphs.  `div` would be a better choice. see accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think using javascript for a simple css trick is overkill.
Here is the one i made just now:
http://jsfiddle.net/t6R93/

```
div{
  display: table-row;
}
label,input{
  display:table-cell;
}
```

PS: It may have flaws with other browsers. I only tested with Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use JavaScript, jQuery, or additional `div`s. You just have to:

- Float both `input` and `label` to left (note that `input` has to be block to be floated).
- Add `clear: both` to `label`.
- Set fixed width (e.g. `100px`) to `label`.

```css
input {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
label {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset id="o-bs-sum-buginfo">
  <label for="o-bs-sum-bug-ErrorPrefix">Error Prefix</label>
  <input type="text" id="o-bs-sum-bug-ErrorPrefix" name="ErrorPrefix" value="" />

  <label for="o-bs-sum-bug-ErrorNumber">Error Number</label>
  <input type="text" id="o-bs-sum-bug-ErrorNumber" name="ErrorNumber" value="" />
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was curious to see if this could be done with the "natural" semantic markup, i.e. with no non-semantic wrapper elements and with the `label` containing its corresponding `input` rather than having to refer to it with the slightly clunky `for` attribute:

```
<fieldset>
  <label>Error Prefix<input/></label>
  <label>Error Number<input/></label>
</fieldset>
```

A fixed-width label won't align the inputs here because the text isn't a separate element, and Shahid's elegantly minimal solution doesn't work either, but if you're willing to make all inputs the same width (which IMHO looks nice anyway) you can `float` them `right`:

```
label { display:block; margin:8px; width:360px; clear:right; overflow:auto; }
input, button, textarea, select { box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; width:200px; float:right; }
```

The `-moz-box-sizing` should be redundant when FF29 is released, and even the `box-sizing` isn't needed unless you're mixing form control types. The `clear` and `overflow` are specifically needed for `textarea`.

Full mixed-input-type example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Aligned labels</title>
    <style>
      label { display:block; margin:8px; width:360px; clear:right; overflow:auto; }
      input, button, textarea, select { box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; width:200px; float:right; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label>Name<input type="text" value="Sir Galahad of Camelot"/></label>
    <label>Quest<textarea>I seek the Holy Grail</textarea></label>
    <label>Favourite Colour<select><option>Blue</option><option>Yellow</option></select></label>
    <label>If you're sure...<button>Give Answers</button></label>
  </body>
</html>
```