# How do I format forms so they align vertically?

Tags: html, css, forms

I am trying to create a form for people to contact me but can't get it to look nice. I can't get the forms to align vertically and I also can't get the Message label to display on the top left side of the textarea instead of the bottom left.

```
<form id="contact" name="contact" method="post">
<label for="name"><br>
  Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<label for="email"><br>
  Email:</label>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email">
<label for="subject"><br>
  Subject:</label>
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject">
<label for="message"><br>
  Message:</label>
<textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Please post a jsFiddle sample and your stylesheet. Also note that your HTML is invalid (`<input>` cannot be an immediate child of `<form>`).

Comment: Add a `<br>` after the Message label and then it will be on top left of the text area instead of the bottom

Comment: I'm not using a stylesheet on this yet and I don't understand why you're saying the HTML is invalid.

Comment: Look at this question and this is answered:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193848/i-want-my-label-to-vertically-align-with-my-input-field

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `<br>` but if you want to, move it outside of the `label` and before the `input`.

Alternatively, set your labels to be displayed as block level items:

```
label {display: block}
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/ixurUMU/1/

The reason it's not working how you want it to is that labels aren't block-level elements. They are inline. Meaning they will not in any way trigger a 'line break' by default.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<form id="contact" name="contact" method="post">
    <label for="name">
        Name:</label>
    <input class="textbox" type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <label for="email">
        Email:</label>
    <input class="textbox" type="email" name="email" id="email">
    <label for="subject">
        Subject:</label>
    <input class="textbox" type="text" name="subject" id="subject">
    <label for="message">
        Message:</label>
    <textarea class="textbox" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
```

**CSS**

```
.textbox {display: block}
```

## [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aJMpC/4/)

You can also use this

**HTML**

```
<form id="contact" name="contact" method="post">
    <label class="label" for="name">
        Name:</label>
    <input class="textbox" type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
    <label class="label" for="email">
        Email:</label>
    <input class="textbox" type="email" name="email" id="email"><br>
    <label class="label"  for="subject">
        Subject:</label>
    <input class="textbox" type="text" name="subject" id="subject"><br>
    <label class="label" for="message">
        Message:</label>
    <textarea class="textbox" name="message" id="message"></textarea><br>
      <label class="label" for="message">
        </label>  
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
```

**CSS**

```
.textbox {display: inline-block;}
.label
{
    display: inline-block;
     width: 60px;
}
```

## [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aJMpC/10/)